# How to get the exact used RAM percentage in Grafana?

Tags: linux, bash, collectd, grafana

AM using **collectd** to collect the metrics from the system, am using **Influxdb** as a database to collectd the metrics and **Grafana** for visualization.
I need only the **used RAM memory in percentage** to display in grafana....

I need only the used memory value to show up in grafana exclusing the cached and buffered.

As of now i query grafana like

```
 SELECT mean("value") *-1+100 FROM "memory_value" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/ AND "type" = 'percent' AND "type_instance" = 'free') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval),"host"
```

Which gives the wrong value..
Can anyone pls help me how to display the used RAM percentage

Comment: Why are you meaning the value? What's the expected value? Are you expecting cached memory to be counted as free? This question is fairly poorly written and has little research to show, I'd recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Ginnungagap I mean...I need only the used memory value to show up in grafana exclusing the cached and buffered...

Comment: So you basically want the sum of all memory minus the used one? Instead of just the free memory?

Comment: @Ginnungagap can u help me to that pls...

Comment: @Ginnungagap yes, i need free memory